# How not to deploy under git controled db.sqlite3 file

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my django project, db.sqlite3 is under git control(I chose to do so).  However when deploying the project to AWS server(using elastic beanstalk), I would like not to deploy db.sqlite3 file.

Database setting is configured inside settings module so even db.sqlite3 file is deployed to the server, the project won't reference db.sqlite3 file.  I will probably work fine but I do not want to deploy something unnecessary(db.sqlite3) to be deployed to the server.

How can I not to deploy db.sqlite3 under git control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `.ebignore` file, which has similar structure as `.gitignore`.

Be sure to add whole `.gitignore` content, as well as `db.sqlite3`.

More info in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore).